# SQLite3 query in PHP not querying?

Tags: php, html, sqlite

I have a register page on my site which feeds POST data into a PHP file, which then `INSERT`s it into a database. The problem is, the query:

```
class DB extends SQLite3{
    function __construct(){
            $this->open('db/userpass.db');
    }
}

$db = new DB();

$db->query("INSERT INTO userpass VALUES($user, $encrypted_pass)");
```

isn't querying. Picture book is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnxFF.jpg

You can see my problem in the album. However, I most definitely `query`'d.

Comment: You don't check the result of `$db->query`.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel What do I do then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT` performs a query, `INSERT` doesn't. [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.exec.php) must be used instead.

However, because you are merging data in your command, you better use [statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3stmt.php):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO userpass VALUES(:user, :encrypted_pass)');
$stmt->bindValue(':user', $user);
$stmt->bindValue(':encrypted_pass', $encrypted_pass);
if ($stmt->execute()==FALSE) {
    //handle errors here!
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I wasn't aware. `query` = read data, `exec` = write data.